# Build executable and embed it as a ressource in another project of the same solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, embedded-resource

My idea is to build a portable frontend/backend application.
The frontend application should extract the backend application and start it with elevated prompt.

I know how to embed external executables and extract them at runtime.

But how to do this within the same solution?

When I build a release or debug the solution the backend must be built first.
The reference have to be updated whether I build a release or debug version.
And at least the frontend should be built with all embedded resources.

Any ideas how to automate these process?

Comment: So what do you want to do now? Have the frontend and backend in the same solution and the backend projects be built first? Or an automatic build for a backend solution when the frontend solution is being built?